# How to Flash a STM32F4 board without any IDE from windows?

Tags: flash, arm, microcontroller, stm32f4discovery

I have created the binary file(.bin / .out / .srec ) which need to be flashed in to a STM32F4 MCU. The binary file am using is a driver for a wireless module .
We generally use our development IDE for flashing the binary in to the MCU
Thing is like i need to find a alternate method for flashing. Is there any alternate way for flashing the binary file in to the IDE. I mean something like a 3rd party tool or , from command line.. etc.. Can u please help me in finding this for STM32F4 MCU.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question:

I think this link will help for STM32
 STM32 ST-Link Utility: 
http://softadvice.informer.com/St_Link_Utility.html

Comment: and github.com/texane/stlink, and openocd also support stlink for flashing.

Comment: also the stm32 I believe has a serial bootloader as well that is easy to use.

Comment: Hi Dwelch....

Thanks for your suggestion...
Do you know some software tool which can be used to flash any MCU of our choice.
I mean a single tool which can flash STM, Renesas, Freescale,TI, MSP controllers.. etc

Or can u suggest me some tools for flashing these MCU?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, that would not make much sense to make a tool like that.  The closest might be an ide/tool vendor that supports a number of platforms, but likely not all at once (and you would need to likely pay for each).

Comment: JLink is able to flash most of the ARM MCUs

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF258168) is the Official Flash Utility link for STM devices from ST.